# How to send selected option value in form action in django

Tags: django

I want to send the l.id value in the action which I will match in urlconf.

```
<form name="move_form" action="{% url index %}move_review/" method="post">
<select name="to_lst">

{% if list1 %}
{% for l in list1 %}
    <OPTION value={{ l.id }}>{{l.name }}-{{ l.age }}</OPTION>
{% endfor %}
{% else %}
<OPTION> None </OPTION>
{% endif %}
</select>

<INPUT type="submit" value="Accept" ><INPUT type="Reset">
```

What I want is to make the url like `<mainip>/move_review/{l.id}/`

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: so when you click on submit you want to redirect to that page/view, right?

Comment: yes sammy. i tried several things. but i am not able to figure it out properly.

Comment: ok, change the `method="post"` to `method="get"` and see if it hits the url, means in the top on the url you can see the to_lst

Comment: let me try. Will update here.

Comment: Did a workaround by keeping the method as post. it is working now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
def your_function(request):
  id = request.POST.get("to_lst",None)
  #Do something 
  return render(request,"your_template.html")
```

In this case you need  not pass id in urls.let form take care of it

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But suppose, in the context dictionary i am sending a key value pair which i am not using in the template. but i want that key value pair to be available for the next view which gets invoked from the form action. what do i want to do in that case?

Comment: Got it. Done. Thanks for the support.